# Binding to a method using Polymer

Tags: javascript, html, model-view-controller, polymer

When using Polymer, is it possible to bind to a method rather than a value? E.g.

```
<div>{{someMethod()}}</div>
```

or

```
<div>{{someMethod}}</div>
```

Judging from the source and docs, it is not. Just wanted to confirm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not directly, but there are a couple of ways to probably achieve what you want. I'm assuming you want to transform data...?

1. Define a property as an **ES5 getter**

   A bit of a cheat, but you can define a property as a getter and then wrap custom logic around the value that's returned.

   ```
   <div>{{likes}}</div>

   Polymer('my-tag', {
     firstName: 'John',
     get likes() {
       return this.firstName + ' ' + lastName + ' likes bread';
     }
   });
   ```

   Demo: http://jsbin.com/nuyuqote/3/edit

   **Note:** Use this optional cautiously. Binding to a getter doesn't work under `Object.observe()`, which Polymer will use if supported. See [Scott's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22030380/binding-to-a-method-using-polymer#comment33403031_22031522) below.
2. **Custom filters**

   Not documented yet :(

   ```
   <div>{{'thingy' | upperCaseFilter}}</div>

   Polymer('my-tag', {
     upperCaseFilter: function(value) {
       return value.toUpperCase();
     }
   });
   ```

   Demo: http://jsbin.com/nuyuqote/1/edit
3. **`<prop>Changed`**

   See [Scott's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22030380/binding-to-a-method-using-polymer#comment33403031_22031522) below.

BTW, one reason we don't have something like `{{someMethod()}}` in Polymer is that that executes JavaScript. It's generally considered an anti-pattern to do something like `onclick="someMethod()"` because it's easy to subject yourself to things like XSS attacks.

Comment: It's not a good idea to bind to a getter. `Object.observe` cannot observe getters without extra code, so there will be trouble when you switch to a platform with native observation. Polymer's observation and binding system usually can do what you want without having to use getters or setters. For example, instead of the getter one could use `firstnameChanged` (http://jsbin.com/nuyuqote/5/edit). If you don't want `likes` property to exist, the filter solution is the best choice.

Comment: Posted this question under the wrong SO account. Anyways, thanks for the information. Would custom filters also be my best option if I wanted the bound value to inject html rather than text? It seems like this is not the case, and raw binding may not work for html injection.

Comment: If you want to inject HTML, you could reference a node in the shadow  root and set `.innerHTML` in the `Changed` handler. `<div id="mycontainer"></div>` and `this.$.mycontainer.innerHTML = '<b>bold text!</b>';`